# Reasoing behing dividing by time to get the tangent vector from the difference in the position vector

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

I understand why we divide by time taken from one positon to other in case of normal derivatives because slope by definition includes the time axis difference for slope in normal distance time graph .

> But when we come to position graph why is that there too we divide by time as in we already have slope by taking the difference of the two position vectors isnt ? Why dividing by delta t so as to get slope ? Which is the tangent vector . Cannot we just take  $\Delta{t}$ tends to 0 then the difference of position vector will give a vector very close to being tangent? [image]

[image]

Comment: Damn production quality really dipped from 2nd to 3rd image

Comment: Just check Kleppner and Kolenkow, it explains this very well.

Comment: [Pdf hosted online](https://bayanbox.ir/view/7764531208313247331/Kleppner-D.-Kolenkow-R.J.-Introduction-to-Mechanics-2014.pdf)

Comment: The "slope" you get when working with vectors isn't the same slope that you get in a position versus time plot. In the former, it refers to the direction of motion. In the latter, it gives you a rate of change (distance/time). Velocity is all about distance traveled per unit time (think meters/second), and that's exactly what the slope gives you in a position versus time plot, not in the vector case.

Comment: Work it out in a simple case like $\,x = t^2\,$, $\,\mathbf r = t \,\mathbf i + t^2 \,\mathbf j\,$, and it should become more clear.

Comment: Now i understood thanks @infinitylord ,dxiv ,ethakka